# How to convert string to int in java to get calculation

Tags: java

How to convert string to int to get calculation

```
String a="2-1";
```

How to convert this string to int to get value as 1

Comment: I would split the string into chars and treat each char separately.. If it's a number 0-9, convert to int, if its a math symbol (+,-,/-*) extract that too

Comment: `if (a.equals("2-1")) return "1"`

Answer (score 0):

1. split the string by "-"
2. store the index0 and index1 in 2 different variables.
3. use - operator to subtract index1 from index0

Answer (score 0):

```
    String a = "2-1";
    String[] split = a.split("-"); //split string by regex -
    int rs = Integer.valueOf(split[0]) - Integer.valueOf(split[1]); //parse string to integer and subtract
    System.out.println("Result= " + rs);
```

Answer (score 0):

If your strings are in **x-y** simplicity, it's best to split and do operations as suggested in other replies.
However if you want more complext evaluations e.g **(x+y)/2*z-2**, you need an expression evaluator. See this post: ["Evaluating a math expression given in string form"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3422673/evaluating-a-math-expression-given-in-string-form)

Answer (score 0):

You could find another anwers in here:  [Is there an eval() function in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2605032/is-there-an-eval-function-in-java)

In javascript, eval() does what you want.  In that link you could see the alternatives to eval(), in Java.

Answer (score -1):

Here is the complete function for subtraction and addition you can edit it for other operators too:

```
public int getResult() {
        String input = "2-1";
        char[] charArray = input.toCharArray(); //split string in to three characters
        int result = 0;
        if(charArray[1] == '-')
       {
         result = Integer.valueOf(charArray[0]) - Integer.valueOf(charArray[2]); //if input is subtract minus the variables
       }
       else if (charArray[1] == '+')
      {

        result = Integer.valueOf(charArray[0]) - Integer.valueOf(charArray[2]); //if input is addition, add the variables

      }
       return result;
    }
```